# how to download html table to excel format in php

Tags: php

i am displaying mysql data in html table.

How can i download it in msexcel format by using php. I am using pagination also. The download should be complete table.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this component](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/). You must do the same select which you do to display a table in html, and then to fill the component structure. The comoponent contains a lot of examples of.

Answer (score 0):

try giving these headers: `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my_excel_file.xls");` and  `header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;");` and then  output normal HTML with table in it

Comment: it is downloading but how to show the data. i need to write select query or wht